# Access similar lines from a file and apply a function

Tags: python

I am trying to access similar lines from a file and then apply a sum on their values.

Here is my input file format:

```
K1 20
K2 23
K3 24
K3 14
K3 10
K2 5
```

So, my goal is to create an output file that creates a sum of values per record:

```
K1 20
K2 28
K3 48
```

- It is a big text file >20GB. So I cannot store the whole thing into memory at once.
- I was successful in reading the file in to chunks and do the sums per record for those chunks, now I want to merge these output chunks.

For example first chunk

```
K1 20
K2 23
K3 24
```

second chunk

```
K3 24
K2 5
```

Now I am lost at how do I merge them all and keep updating the records with their new values.

New values after merging will be

K1 20

K2 28

K3 48

Comment: How do you store the chunks?

Comment: First I did chunk=file.readlines(size) and then stored the chunk in a defaultdict and just sum their values per record.

Comment: You might take a look at so called `Counter` which are provided by the `collections` module.

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to sum the values per record, not count the frequency of a record.

Comment: `Counter` can count anything that you want... *count of a missing element is zero*

Comment: Yes but my file is >20 GB and it lot more records that Counter can handle, aka Memory error.

Comment: How many distinct `KN` values do you have?

Comment: Probably 4 million

Comment: So... apparently you didn't bother trying this, right? Because I just did `from collections import Counter; c = Counter; for num in range(5000000): c[num] += 42` (actually I used `randint` but I can't be bothered to press backspace) and it uses less than 1GB of RAM. Not only that, but I thought well *maybe* strings just take up way more memory, so I did the same thing but with `c[str(num)] = randint(1, 1000000)`, and Mac's activity monitor reports 1.17GB. So, you *didn't actually try it*, did you?

Comment: Thanks Wayne for this demo. I appreciate it. You are right Counter works for this specific file. But I am not looking to solve this problem with Counter or defaultdict. I am looking for an efficient solution that can work with files close to 80GB or even 100 GB where I have records >=160 million. I tried defaultdict and Counter and I got memory error for those files. Hence, I decided to post my problem here.

Comment: Then *that's* the question that you should have asked, along with mentioning the fact that you tried with both defaultdict *and* counter. Which would probably take about 32GB of RAM. At that point I probably would use a sqlite DB for the counter.

Answer (score 1):

The following should accomplish the desired functionality.

```
from collections import Counter

output = Counter()

with open("input.txt") as file:
    for line in file.read().split('\n'):
        if line:
            key, value = line.split()

            output[key] += int(value)

with open("output.txt", 'w+') as file:
    for key, value in output.items():
        file.write("{key} {value}\n".format(key=key, value=value))
```

Comment: You could use `collections.Counter` for this and then you could skip the `key in output` part

Comment: @WayneWerner True. I updated my answer to use a `defaultdict`, though, as it has a cleaner solution here.

Comment: `Counter()` is just `defaultdict(int)`. With a couple of other fancy methods.

Comment: @WayneWerner Interesting. Updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

> It is a big text file >20GB. So I cannot store the whole thing into memory at once.

1. It does not matter how big the file is. What matters is how many unique records are there because you will be keeping only unique records.
2. Python `Counter` would still be keeping it in memory. That is not going to do any good to you if you are running in a constrained environment.

---

My suggestion:

- Sort the file in the alphabetical order. I would just send it via unix `sort`. (I am assuming you have space on your FS)
- Iterate over lines. Extract the first portion of the current record. Iterate while the first portion of the record is the same -- while summing up the second part.
- When the record type changes -- write one line to the file -- with the sum you have been holding in your memory until now.
- Repeat.